# How to customize the color and fonts for microsoft Adaptivecards Input.choiceset

Tags: javascript, adaptive-cards

I'm using v1.2 of the AdaptiveCard SDK in BotFramework Webchat. I need to customize the color of the values of the Input.Choiceset of the Microsoft adaptive cards.
I need to use it in the AdaptivecardhostConfig.

[Input choice list which is being used in my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfNPE.png)

Comment: Hi Shriya, try including more of your question in your question. You've got so many links that the system thinks you're a spammer!

Comment: Hi Zach , it is not a spammer.
I really need the solution for this question.

Comment: You are able to edit your question

Comment: Could you please help me on this question which i asked. I have a project to complete and deadline is coming closer. 

Only this part of the code is remaining.

In adaptive cards which is being used for thr botframework webchat, I want to change the font color of the values present in the Input.Choiceset of the Adaptive card.